# "Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/scim/#provision-and-invite-users"}

Tags: onelogin, scim

I want to make a link between OneLogin(Unlimited plan) and Github using SCIM.

The setting work was done with reference to [this support page](https://onelogin.service-now.com/support?id=kb_article&sys_id=5aa91d03db109700d5505eea4b96197e).

However, result of running step 1 of "Testing GitHub Provisioning" will "Failed".

**error message** is below.

> User failed creating in app. Response json: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/scim/#provision-and-invite-users"}

I actually try to access the above URL. The above URL's anchor does not exist. But, there was a https://developer.github.com/v3/scim/#provision-and-invite-a-scim-user very similar to above.

Kindly tell me the solution for this error.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for inconvenience.

I neglected to manually switch to "Approved".

https://onelogin.service-now.com/support?id=kb_article&sys_id=5f0e6dfedba99c1024c780c74b961953&kb_category=c23a69f0db185340d5505eea4b9619de

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQkCK.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't configured your SCIM base URL correctly and so OneLogin is trying to access a non-SCIM endpoint at github.

The SCIM base URL in your application should be something along the lines of

```
https://api.github.com/scim/v2/organizations/your_organization
```

It's also possible your instance of GitHub isn't configured for SCIM? To better debug what's going on try entering the SCIM base URL you have configured in your OneLogin application into a browser and add **/Users** to the end of the URL.

This will show what OneLogin is getting as part of the response (and it may well be an HTML error page, rather than the JSON response OneLogin is expecting)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I tried to access below.
https://api.github.com/scim/v2/organizations/(targetOrganizationName)/Users

Then, the following text appeared in my browser.

> “{
> "message": "Not Found",
> "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/scim/#get-a-list-of-provisioned-identities"
> }”

I'm not sure if this text is a normal.
So, I'm asking Github support as to whether this reaction is normal.

Comment: I am sorry for inconvenience.

I neglected to manually switch to "Approved".

https://onelogin.service-now.com/support?id=kb_article&sys_id=5f0e6dfedba99c1024c780c74b961953&kb_category=c23a69f0db185340d5505eea4b9619de